# Is there a way to host Razor pages in console application using ServiceTask?

Tags: razor, markdown, servicestack

I'm trying to make a console application to expose JSON services.
In addition I'd like to host html and js pages to use them.
I put the *.md (even *.htm) files into Views folder, but I can't reach them.

If I add a route ".Add("/Test")" (where  MyMarkdownView : MarkdownViewBase), i even get a "KeyNotFoundException The given key was not present in the dictionary." exception.

Is it generally possible, or I should make my own service (similar to https://github.com/jimschubert/blogs/blob/master/2012-07-15/RazorExample/Main.cs) to host them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be interested in the [Razor Rockstars](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples/tree/master/src/RazorRockstars/RazorRockstars.Console) Console Application that uses **embedded resource** MVC Razor views that work with (or without) existing [ServiceStack web services](http://www.servicestack.net/).

i.e. the example project shows the 3 different ways to host MVC Razor pages in ServiceStack:

1. [Service/Controller and Model](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples/blob/master/src/RazorRockstars/RazorRockstars.Console/Views/Rockstars.cshtml) - Using the **Response DTO** from the [Web Service](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples/blob/master/src/RazorRockstars/RazorRockstars.Console/AppHost.cs#L91) as a **view model**
2. [No Service/Controller](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples/blob/master/src/RazorRockstars/RazorRockstars.Console/TypedModelNoController.cshtml) - **Directly** using the **Request DTO** as the view model
3. [No Service/Controller or Model](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples/blob/master/src/RazorRockstars/RazorRockstars.Console/NoModelNoController.cshtml) - **Directly** by using a **dynamic view model**