# How to host a website using console application and ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack

I have a console application with ServiceStack which host Razor files and JSON services according to [Is there a way to host Razor pages in console application using ServiceTask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11971576/is-there-a-way-to-host-razor-pages-in-console-application-using-servicetask) .

I'd like to have an access to the JS and Image files. Currently I've made a service which does the ReadAllText from the file and return a string. There are several problems in this solution:

- It requires me to distinguish between binary and text files.
- No subfolders.
- Should care about ContentType.

Is there are standard functionality or service I can use out of box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YEs, now there is - see here: http://razor.servicestack.net/#complete-stack